# Does the shape of the domains matter when doing analytic continuation along a path? Textbooks don't agree

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

**Area:** Analytic Continuation in Complex Analysis

**Question** Does the shape of the domain matter when doing analytic continuation along a path?

**Background** I have been reading up on the concept of analytic continuation and have realized that some textbooks introduce the concept of *analytic continuation along a path* with the help of disks (see image below)

[image: Analytic continuation from z1 to z4]

but other textbooks (for example Needham (1997) page 251) seem to let the domains connecting the points look like anything.

[image: Visual Complex Analysis, Needham (1997)]

I guess that some authors like to introduce the concept with the help of power series representation of analytic functions and therefore using disks for the continuation but this seems cheap in my opinion if one could introduce it like Needham and letting the reader know that the domains can look like anything and are not confined to only be disks.

But I start to doubt myself when I look at wikipedia and other theorems connected to this area since for example Monodromy theorem uses disks as the shapes on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy_theorem).

Anyone can let me know if the shape of the domain matters when doing analytic continuation along a path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly, it doesn't matter if we perform analytic continuation using disks or general connected open sets: The resulting notions of analytic continuation along a path coincide.

Every connected open set is path-connected, and may be written as a union of open disks. In a connected open set, analytic continuation along a path using open disks is unique.

If instead we perform analytic continuation along a path using arbitrary connected open sets, the preceding paragraph reduces us to using disks.

---

Restricting to disks may be technically and conceptually simpler (sometimes less is more even when it comes to choices), and disks are the natural regions of convergence of power series.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew, so in short, it is the same result and it is just a choice from the author which one to use since as you said you could reduce the connected open sets to a union of disks.

Comment: Yes, that's right, and you're welcome! <> An advantage of disks is their connection with power series, while an advantage of arbitrary open sets (such as planes with branch cuts removed) is the ability to use fewer of them in practice. Each tool has good uses, and it's important to know the resulting notions of analytic continuation are the same. (Which is to say, yours is a great question.)